# Mixing a 8gb ram with a 4gb ram?

Tags: dual-channel

I have a lenovo G40 80 latop with Intel i3 4005u processor and 4GB DDR33l 1600 RAM. I want to add some RAM for virtualization purposes so I am thinking to add a 8GB SoDIMM so that later I can add another 8GB to get 16GB. But after searching about the matter I got to know that adding different size of DIMMs will affect the channel system.

Is it significant enough to rationalize buying of a 4 GB of ram rather then 8GB?

Comment: Different number, but essentially same question as http://superuser.com/questions/229908/is-it-better-to-have-4gb-ram-in-dual-channel-or-6gb-as-single-channel.  - What is better, more RAM or slightly less dual channel - and will ti work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not worth buying a 4GB stick.  Even if the board does support dual channel mode, both RAM sticks have to be exactly the same for dual channel to work, so just buying another 4GB stick probably won't even give you dual channel mode.

This is all beside the point, though, because 12GB of RAM will basically always be better than 8GB, dual channel or not.

Answer (score 0):

No its not. I'm personally running 2 * 4GB + 2 * 8GB and it works just fine. (In dual channel)

Comment: First of all thanks for your help. I guess you have a desktop with four ram ports with color coding. I only have 2 ports and want to use two different sizes. Is it possible to gain dual channel advantage in my case?

Comment: I don't think so, but the advantage really isn't that noticable in real-world performance anyway. Although what might happen is that dualchannel will work for 4GB/Channel and the other 4 GB from your 8GB stick will be slightly slower.